# Francesca Neural pt-BR using styles

Tags: azure, voice

Is there any documentation to inform the styles that can be used with Francisca Neural?

For example:

```py
xml_body = ElementTree.Element('speak', version='1.0')
xml_body.set('{http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace}lang', 'pt-BR')
xml_body.set('xmlns:mstts', 'https://www.w3.org/2001/mstts')

voice = ElementTree.SubElement(xml_body, 'voice')
voice.set('name', 'Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (pt-BR, FranciscaNeural)')

mstts = ElementTree.SubElement(voice, 'mstts:express-as')
mstts.set('style', 'cheerful')

prosody = ElementTree.SubElement(mstts, 'prosody')
prosody.set('rate', '0%')

body = ElementTree.tostring(xml_body)
```

I tried to use `cheerful` , but I didn't see any change in the voice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, speaking style adjustments are supported for these neural voices:

```
en-US-AriaNeural
en-US-JennyNeural
en-US-GuyNeural
zh-CN-XiaoxiaoNeural
zh-CN-YunyangNeural
zh-CN-YunyeNeural
zh-CN-YunxiNeural (Preview)
zh-CN-XiaohanNeural (Preview)
zh-CN-XiaomoNeural (Preview)
zh-CN-XiaoxuanNeural (Preview)
zh-CN-XiaoruiNeural (Preview)
```

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-synthesis-markup?tabs=csharp#adjust-speaking-styles

Earlier, the PT-BR Francesca Neural did support the Style adjustments and was documented in the above the article . But has been redacted/removed owing to known  issue which the MS Product group is working.

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/52032